# initscripts conflicts with 1:redhat-release-server

Tags: openssl, centos7, rpm, yum

When I try to install openssl-devel on centos 7 i get this error, have anyone encountered this error and have a solution?

```
Error: initscripts conflicts with 1:redhat-release-server-7.1-1.0.2.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to install an older version of `openssl-devel`, like one from CentOS6 or something. Where did it come from?

Comment: I am trying to install on OS : Oracle Linux Server release 7.1
openssl-devel.x86_64 1:1.0.2k-12.0.1.el7